# What does "warning: override: VZ_FAIRSCHED changes choice state" mean?

Tags: kernel, configuration

I am building a Linux kernel, via the Debian linux-2.6 source package.

Now there's CONFIG_VZ_FAIRSCHED=y in a sub-config, which gets merged into the final .config, where apparently also "y" gets used:

```
# grep FAIRSCHED debian/config/**/*
debian/config/featureset-openvz/config:CONFIG_VZ_FAIRSCHED=y
```

The .config used during build:

```
# grep FAIRSCHED debian/build/build_amd64_openvz_amd64/.config
CONFIG_VZ_FAIRSCHED=y
```

I could understand the warning, if now "n" would be used, but nothing appears to have been changed?!

This is the output during the `make -f debian/rules.gen binary-arch_amd64_openvz_amd64 binary-indep` call:

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/var/lib/vz/private/linux.nobackup/linux-2.6/debian/build/source_amd64_openvz'
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/docproc
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/hash
  GEN     /var/lib/vz/private/linux.nobackup/linux-2.6/debian/build/build_amd64_openvz_amd64/Makefile
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/conf.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/kxgettext.o
  SHIPPED scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.c
  SHIPPED scripts/kconfig/lex.zconf.c
  SHIPPED scripts/kconfig/zconf.hash.c
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
scripts/kconfig/conf -R arch/x86/Kconfig
.config:3518:warning: override: VZ_FAIRSCHED changes choice state
```

What is this warning referring to?

Answer (score 2):

Blind guess: `CONFIG_VZ_FAIRSCHED=y` forces a value in *some other* kernel configuration option. What does the help text for that option state?

Comment: Here's the part from the OpenVZ patch, it does not appear to do much.

+config VZ_FAIRSCHED                                                                                                                 
+ bool "OpenVZ groups"
+ help
+   This option add customizable task groups with OpenVZ compatible
+   syscall and procfs interface.
+